# ANTLR tree walker , multiple times of return value

Tags: java, parsing, tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a tree walker like this:

```
function:
    ^(FUNCTION_TOK fcname=IDENTIFIER param=functionParameters*){
        a_param_arrayList.add(param);
    }
;

functionParameters returns [Object sth]:
    ^(PARAM_TOK value=IDENTIFIER){ sth = $value.getText();}
;
```

This is a simple scenario,I just want to add the parameters to an arraylist, but the code above(**a_param_arrayList.add(param)**) will only collects the first parameter and ignores the others.But **functionParameters** actually parases multiple parameters.

Does anyone know how to fix this tree walker?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by using arguments of rules.

```
function:
    ^(FUNCTION_TOK fcname=IDENTIFIER functionParameters[a_param_arraylist]*)
;

functionParameters [ArrayList arr] returns [Object sth]:
    ^(PARAM_TOK value=IDENTIFIER){ sth = $value.getText(); arr.add(sth);}
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the list label assignment (+=)?  See http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+Cheat+Sheet

```
^(FUNCTION_TOK fcname=IDENTIFIER param += functionParameters*){
```